# grabbing a screenshot from gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

So yeah we're trying to display a pretty small version of the map and all the user interface elements were getting in the way.. and we realized a screenshot would probably be just fine, so just wondering if it's possible to generate a screenshot of a map position and just have it display as an image instead of an interactable map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Google Static Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to show a non-interactive map without user interface controls (zooming buttons etc.)

As they return an image file it is easy to cache. Please note that Google does not allow caching of maps due to copyright reasons of the map owner, but probably caching is not necessary with the static map.

Comment: great alternative and warning, +1

Comment: So they can cache any one's copyrighted blog content but we can't cache their maps?!

Comment: As Google tells you not to cache their Maps (which is btw. mostly not their own content but the Map's owners content, Google has licensed it for you to use freely) you can [tell Google not to cache your page](http://www.seoconsultants.com/meta-tags/robots/googlebot).